# Wrote a nested if else procedure that returns the answer AND "none". Why?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, nonetype

> > > def is_friend (name):
> > >           if name[0] == 'D':
> > >               print 'yes'
> > >           else:
> > >               if name [0] == 'N':
> > >                   print 'yes'
> > >               else:
> > >                   print 'no'
> > >
> > > print is_friend ('Eric')
> > >       no
> > >       None

Answer (score 0):

Use return on your if else statements instead of print and then it will work.

```
def is_friend(name): if name[0] == 'D': return 'yes' else: if name[0] == 'N'return 'yes' else: return 'no'
print is_friend('Eric')
```